# MySQL: SUM() does not provide sum when used with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, sum

This produces one column with 10 numerical rows:

```
SELECT (`sales`.`sale_shipping`) as `total_shipping`
FROM `sales` 
LEFT JOIN `contacts` ON `sales`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`contact_id` 
LEFT JOIN `salespayments` ON `salespayments`.`sale_id` = `sales`.`sale_id` 
LEFT JOIN `contactsadditionalreps` ON `contacts`.`contact_id` = `contactsadditionalreps`.`contact_id` 
WHERE `salespayments`.`payment_type`!='Refund' 
GROUP BY `sales`.`sale_id`
```

I would like the sum to be returned of the 10 results, however instead of returning the sum, this returns 10 rows with strange values:

```
SELECT SUM(`sales`.`sale_shipping`) as `total_shipping`
FROM `sales` 
LEFT JOIN `contacts` ON `sales`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`contact_id` 
LEFT JOIN `salespayments` ON `salespayments`.`sale_id` = `sales`.`sale_id` 
LEFT JOIN `contactsadditionalreps` ON `contacts`.`contact_id` = `contactsadditionalreps`.`contact_id` 
WHERE `salespayments`.`payment_type`!='Refund' 
GROUP BY `sales`.`sale_id`
```

The problem is, instead of summing the rows, it sums something else.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: If you're expecting a single row that's the sum of the 10 rows you're currently seeing, then you should remove your `GROUP BY` clause. But as mustaccio pointed out, it's not clear what your goals are with the little details you provided. Please provide more context about your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JOINs` are done first, then the `GROUP BY` together with its aggregates, such as `SUM`.

If you want the `SUM` to be done against a single table, then the `GROUP BY` needs to be against that one table.  Maybe:

```
... FROM ( SELECT sale_id, sale_shipping
              FROM sales
              GROUP BY sale_id ) AS x
    JOIN ...
```